# How can I set a minimum threshold for my LUISDialog to go to None Intent in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have a `LuisDialog` as such:

```
[LuisModel("...", "...", domain: "...")]
[Serializable]
public class MainLUISDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{

   [LuisIntent("None")]
   public async Task Default(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
   {
      await context.PostAsync("Não percebi, podes ser mais claro se faz favor?");
      context.Wait(MessageReceived);
   }

   [LuisIntent("Service.Cancel")]
   public async Task CancelService(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
   {
      await context.PostAsync("Queres cancelar um serviço.");
      await context.PostAsync("Entities:");
      foreach (var entity in result.Entities)
      {
         await context.PostAsync($"{entity.Type}: {entity.Entity}");
      }
      context.Wait(MessageReceived);
   }
...
```

I wanted to know how I can set so that for example all utterances that have an intent score lower than 0.7 will go to the `None` intent, is there any way to programmatically in my code add this threshold? I can't seem to find any way to do this with the code I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be inheriting from `LuisDialog` and override one of these functions:

- [BestIntentFrom](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L180)
- [BestResultFrom](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L192)
- [DispatchToIntentHandler](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L252)

In any of those functions, you should be able to do your logic to discard the intent detected and replace it with None.

If this is just for 1-2 intents, then it might not be worthy to do the overrides and instead, you can just check it in all the intent methods as:

```
 if (result.TopScoringIntent.Score < threshold) 
 {
     return Default(context, result);
 }
```

Comment: Will the "return Default(context, result)" direct to the None Dialog?

Comment: Yes assuming that your [None] intent is mapped to that method, which seems so based on your code